# What Redis data type fit the most for following example

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have following scenario:

1. Fetch array of numbers (from REDIS) ***conditionally***
2. For each number do some async stuff (fetch something from DB based on number)
3. For each thing in result set from DB do another async stuff

*Periodically repeat `1. 2. 3.` because new numbers will be constantly added to REDIS structure.Those numbers represent unix timestamp in milliseconds so out of the box those numbers will always be sorted in time of addition*

**Conditionally** means fetch those unix timestamp from REDIS that are less or equal to current unix timestamp in milliseconds(`Date.now()`)

Question is what REDIS data type fit the most for this use case having in mind that this code will be scaled up to N instances, so N instances will share access to single REDIS instance. To equally share the load each instance will read for example first(oldest) 5 numbers from REDIS. *Numbers are unique* (adding same number should fail silently) so REDIS SET seems like a good choice but reading M first elements from REDIS set seems impossible.

To prevent two different instance of the code to read same numbers REDIS read operation should be atomic, it should read the numbers and delete them. If any async operation fail on specific number (`steps 2. and 3.`), numbers should be added again to REDIS to be handled again. They should be re-added back to the head not to the end to be handled again as soon as possible. As far as i know `SADD` would push it to the tail.

`SMEMBERS key` would read everything, it looks like a hammer to me. I would need to include some application logic to get first five than to check what is less or equal to `Date.now()` and then to delete those and to wrap somehow everything in single transaction. Besides that set cardinality can be huge.
`SSCAN` sounds interesting but i don't have any clue how it works in "scaled" environment like described above. Besides that, per REDIS docs: The SCAN family of commands only offer limited guarantees about the returned elements since the collection that we incrementally iterate can change during the iteration process. Like described above collection will be changed frequently

Comment: Have you considered using Sorted Sets with a Lua script for atomic, score-based popping? If not, is be happy to add details as a full fledged answer

Comment: @ItamarHaber please do so. Please check edits about conditionality in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more appropriate data structure would be the Sorted Set - members have a float score that is very suitable for storing a timestamp and you can perform range searches (i.e. anything less or equal a given value).

The relevant starting points are the [`ZADD`](http://redis.io/commands/zadd), [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) and [`ZREMRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore) commands.

To ensure the atomicity when [reading](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) and [removing](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyscore) members, you can choose between the the following options: [Redis transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions), [Redis Lua script](http://redis.io/commands/eval) and in the next version (v4) a [Redis module](http://antirez.com/news/106).

#### [Transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions)

Using transactions simply means doing the following code running on your instances:

```
MULTI
ZRANGEBYSCORE <keyname> -inf <now-timestamp>
ZREMRANGEBYSCORE <keyname> -inf <now-timestamp>
EXEC
```

Where `<keyname>` is your key's name and `<now-timestamp>` is the current time.

#### [Lua script](http://redis.io/commands/eval)

A Lua script can be cached and runs embedded in the server, so in some cases it is a preferable approach. It is definitely the best approach for short snippets of atomic logic if you need flow control (remember that a MULTI transaction returns the values only after execution). Such a script would look as follows:

```
local r = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], '-inf', ARGV[1])
redis.call('ZREMRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], '-inf', ARGV[1])
return r
```

To run this, first cache it using [`SCRIPT LOAD`](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) and then call it with [`EVALSHA`](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) like so:

```
EVALSHA <script-sha> 1 <key-name> <now-timestamp>
```

Where `<script-sha>` is the sha1 of the script returned by `SCRIPT LOAD`.

#### [Redis modules](http://antirez.com/news/106)

In the near future, once v4 is GA you'll be able to write and use modules. Once this becomes a reality, you'll be able to use this module we've made that provides the [`ZPOP`](http://redismodules.com/commands/zpop/) command and could be extended to cover this use case as well.

Comment: very nice explanation. Just one more question, in proposed solution if unix timestamp is a value what is the score? It seems to me that score will be equal to value right? something like:

`ZADD <keyname> <unix-timestamp> <unix-timestamp>`?

Comment: Also i need to use `LIMIT` with `ZRANGEBYSCORE`, so not to fetch everything that is less or equal to `<now-timestamp>`. So in transaction i should use `ZREMRANGEBYSCORE <keyname> -inf <last-timestamp-returned-by-the-limit>` but i don't see a way in which i can get this last-timestamp. As far as i know i can't get intermediate results from MULTI command? (results from first command in MULTI block to be used in second command in MULTI block)

Comment: Yep, the member and its score would be the same in this case.

Comment: The LIMIT requirement makes a Lua script the right choice in that case.